# Python code yielding different result for same numerical value, depending on inclusion of precision point

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I defined a function which returns a third order polynomial function for either a value, a list or a np.array:

```
def two_d_third_order(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + np.multiply(b, x) + np.multiply(c, np.multiply(x, x)) + np.multiply(d, np.multiply(x, np.multiply(x, x)))
```

The issue I noticed is, however, when I use "two_d_third_order" on the following two inputs:
1500
1500.0
With (a, b, c, d) = (1.20740028e+00, -2.93682465e-03,  2.29938078e-06, -5.09134552e-10), I get two different results:
2.4441
0.2574
, respectively. I don't know how this is possible, and any help would be appreciated.

I tried several inputs, and somehow the inclusion of a floating point on certain values (despite representing the same numerical value) changes the end result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses implicit data type conversions. When you use only integers (like 1500), there is a loss of precision in all subsequent operations. Whereas when you pass it a float or double (like 1500.0), subsequent operations are performed with the associated datatype, i.e in this case with higher precision.

This is not a "bug" so to speak, but generally how Python operates without the explicit declaration of data types. Languages like C and C++ require explicit data type declarations and explicit data type casting to ensure operations are performed in the prescribed precision formats. Can be a boon or a bane depending on usage.

Answer (score 0):

`1500 * 2_250_000` is `3_375_000_000` overflowing the range on `int32`:

```py
print(type(np.multiply(1500, 2250000)))
print(np.multiply(1500, 2250000))
```

giving:

```
<class 'numpy.int32'>
-919967296
```

Where as floats use a much larger container.

```py
print(type(np.multiply(1500.0, 2250000.0)))
print(np.multiply(1500.0, 2250000.0))
```

giving:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
3375000000.0
```

Try casting your input to a larger int.

```py
(a, b, c, d) = (1.20740028e+00, -2.93682465e-03, 2.29938078e-06, -5.09134552e-10)
x1 = np.int64(1500)
x2 = 1500.0
print(two_d_third_order(x1, a, b, c, d) == two_d_third_order(x2, a, b, c, d))
```